# Using regex to parse line breaks and dollar signs in scraped image src using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I am using nokogiri in my rails 4 app to scrape images from websites and some of them give me unexpected '$' after '' errors.

For instance, here is one sample image url output:

```
  <img src="http://x.example.com/images/detail/ln9502/1_ln-9502---

  grh_375.jpg" alt="" style="display: block;">
```

I suspect it is the line break that is giving me trouble?

Here is another:

```
  <img class="abc" src="http://xxx.example.com/is/image/Sample/503508739_1?$sample_size$">
```

I suspect it is the dollar signs giving me issues here.

Here is what I have in one of my controllers that is saving the image:

```
  item_imageurl = page.search(library.image_selector).first.attribute('src').value(/(.|\n|\r)*/).to_s
```

Where I have items that belong to a library and I set the css selector in each library.  Any ideas on what regex I could use to ignore line breaks and dollar signs, unless there's a simpler solution?

Comment: If you make your question more specific you will probably be more likely to get helpful answers. "Any ideas?" is very open ended. Perhaps ask how you would accomplish some specific thing about these URLs. Also, I suggest giving more text describing a) what you want and b) what problem you are having getting that result BEFORE jumping into code.

Comment: My apologies!  Still new to this and hoping it was an obvious fix since most of my problems seem to be that way.  I made an edit to my question.

Comment: I think the `unexpected '$' after ''` error is caused by a bad css query containing a `$` – what is `library.image_selector`?

Comment: it pulls the css image selector stored in each library.  The css selector for the image for both libraries in question do not contain a $

Answer (score 0):

You can remove new lines and whitespace from a string with `.gsub`.

```
  item_imageurl = page.search(library.image_selector).first.attribute('src').value().to_s.gsub(/[\n ]/, "")
```

I'm assuming `...attribute('src').value()` returns the contents of the `src` tag.

For the record, your regex matches the last character of the string. You might want to check out http://regex101.com/ for texting your regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks Cereal, you're correct re: src tag.  I'm still muddling through page scraping but it seems like the issue is with Nokogiri's parsing...so I'm getting an error before I can even manipulate the value itself.  Does this make sense?

Comment: The only experience I have with nokogiri is struggling to get it to install, so I can't help you there. You should update your question with your new information though, someone else knows. I'll suggest you try using `page.search(..)` alone to see how that outputs/if it works.